# Error while installing WisecondorX with conda

Tags: installation, anaconda

I'm trying to install a software called WisecondorX for genetic analysis in Ubuntu 18.04. I type the line below:

```
conda install wisecondorx
```

And get the following output:

> ```
> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
> Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
> Solving environment: | 
> Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
> This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
> Examining backports.functools_lru_cache:  59%|▌| 104/176 [00:00<00:00, 
> 45709.69iExamining tk:  60%|██████████████▎         | 105/176 [00:00<00:00, 45751.29it/s]failed                                                       >                   
>
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
> to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:
>
> Specifications:
>
>   - wisecondorx -> python[version='2.7.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']
>
> Your python: python=3.6
>
> If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
> When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
> not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
> change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
> that.
>
> The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
>
> Package bioconductor-dnacopy conflicts for:
> wisecondorx -> bioconductor-dnacopy
> Package openssl conflicts for:
> python=3.6 -> openssl[version='1.0.*|1.0.*,>=1.0.2l,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2m,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2n,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2p,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a']
> Package scikit-learn conflicts for:
> wisecondorx -> scikit-learn
> Package numpy conflicts for:
> wisecondorx -> numpy
> Package tk conflicts for:
> python=3.6 -> tk[version='8.5.*|8.6.*|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.9,<8.7.0a0']
> Package zlib conflicts for:
> python=3.6 -> zlib[version='1.2.*|1.2.11|1.2.8|>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
> Package scipy conflicts for:
> wisecondorx -> scipy
> Package pip conflicts for:
> python=3.6 -> pip
> Package readline conflicts for:
> python=3.6 -> readline[version='6.2.*|7.*|7.0|>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
> Package r-png conflicts for:
> wisecondorx -> r-png
> Package libstdcxx-ng conflicts for:
> python=3.6 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
> Package futures conflicts for:
> wisecondorx -> futures
> Package libffi conflicts for:
> python=3.6 -> libffi[version='3.2.*|>=3.2.1,<3.3.0a0|>=3.2.1,<4.0a0']
> Package xz conflicts for:
> python=3.6 -> xz[version='5.2.*|>=5.2.3,<5.3.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<5.3.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
> Package libgcc-ng conflicts for:
> python=3.6 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
> Package pysam conflicts for:
> wisecondorx -> pysam
> Package ncurses conflicts for:
> python=3.6 -> ncurses[version='5.9|5.9.*|6.0.*|>=6.0,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<6.2.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0']
> Package bzip2 conflicts for:
> python=3.6 -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.6,<2.0a0']
> Package sqlite conflicts for:
> python=3.6 -> sqlite[version='3.13.*|3.20.*|>=3.20.1,<4.0a0|>=3.22.0,<4.0a0|>=3.23.1,<4.0a0|>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.28.0,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0']
> Package r-jsonlite conflicts for:
> wisecondorx -> r-jsonlite[version='>=1.5']
> ```

Any clue of how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I just bumped into this problem. I was able to get around this using the following:

```
# Create an env, and activate it
$ conda create --name test python=3.6  
$ conda activate test

# Clone and jump into the WisecondorX repo (assumping you already have an ssh key added to your github account)

$ git clone git@github.com:CenterForMedicalGeneticsGhent/WisecondorX.git
$ cd WisecondorX


# Use your environment's python to install the required python packages (Note you will have to install the R dependencies separately using conda).

$ which python
~/.conda/envs/test/bin/python
python setup.py install


# Check to see if WisecondorX has been installed in the test env

$ which WisecondorX
~/.conda/envs/test/bin/WisecondorX

$ WisecondorX newref --help
usage: WisecondorX newref [-h] [--nipt] [--yfrac YFRAC] [--refsize REFSIZE]
                          [--binsize BINSIZE] [--cpus CPUS]
                          infiles [infiles ...] outfile

Create a new reference using healthy reference samples

positional arguments:
  infiles            Path to all reference data files (e.g.
                     path/to/reference/*.npz)
  outfile            Path and filename for the reference output (e.g.
                     path/to/myref.npz)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  --nipt             Use flag for NIPT (e.g. path/to/reference/*.npz)
                     (default: False)
  --yfrac YFRAC      Use to manually set the y read fraction cutoff, which
                     defines gender (default: None)
  --refsize REFSIZE  Amount of reference locations per target (default: 300)
  --binsize BINSIZE  Scale samples to this binsize, multiples of existing
                     binsize only (default: 100000.0)
  --cpus CPUS        Use multiple cores to find reference bins (default: 1)
```

Tight lines!

Answer (score 0):

I did not use conda as I find managing multi environment python versions easier with pyenv. 
I downloaded the package and compiled it in a virtualized python environment(3.8). I again manually compiled the R package in the same virtualized setting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you add some more details to help the OP answer his/her question, please?